# Do not return Stored Procedure result as List

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Do not return Stored Procedure result as List.

### The problem

My stored procedures are working well, but until now I'm bringing up multiple results with them. My wish to now is bring only one result.

Look to my query:

```
Select product.Name as productName, measure.Abbreviation as measureAbbreviation
From bm_products As product
Join bm_measures As measure On measure.Id = product.MeasureId
Where product.Id = productId;
```

As you can see, I'm searching for one product with a specified ID. When I execute this procedure, my result is:

[image: Preview 1]

I've already ran the function import and I make this builder (`Builders/Products.cs`) to bring to me the result of the query:

```
public static List<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>
                   BuildItemToShoppingList(Nullable<int> productId)
{
    List<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result> product = 
    db.
       getSpecificProductToShoppingList(productId).
       ToList<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>();
    return product;
}
```

Yes, it is generating me a List because I'm saying to generate,  but the point is: I just have one result — I do not need a List of results.

How can I change the builder to work like I want?

### Details

I'm using C#.Net + MVC 4 + Entity Framework 5 + Razor Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result
                   BuildItemToShoppingList(Nullable<int> productId)
{
    getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result product = 
    db.
       getSpecificProductToShoppingList(productId).FirstOrDefault();
    return product;
}
```

Will return the first object in the list or null if there is no such object.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about how to _generate_ a method that returns the one object with the tools mentioned.

Comment: There was a problem: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyApp.Models.Data.getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.Models.Data.getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>'`

Comment: The code I posted should work as it is. Try to remove the ToList..() part because that should be unneeded now.

Comment: Do you having `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't saw that you changed the method type. In the view I set this model: `@model MyApp.Models.Data.getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result` and I tried to display something in the screen using this: `@Model.measureAbbreviation` but I get this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. Any idea? :( Thanks for your help.

Comment: @chiefGui If the object then you try to retrieve with the StoredProcedure doesn't exist then then `FirstOrDefault()` will return null. You'll need to check to make sure that it isn't null.